# Help finding an S-shaped curve which has the following properties?

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

I am programming a function that takes an angle and returns an angle. I've been having trouble fitting a curve or equation to the properties I want:

1. The ranges of input and output $\theta$ are between 0° and 180°.
2. If $\theta<30^\circ$ or $\theta>150^\circ$, the curve is almost linear.
3. In between these extremes is where I want the main S-curve portion. My main goal is to skip through 90° very quickly, while having a slope under 1 for most of the part before and after 90°. So that if I was incrementing my inputs, there would be very few outputs close to 90°. But an input of say 60° might only produce an output of 45°.

Comment: Do you mean "0 to 180 degrees"? Given that the function you want should be odd, it's not going to be S-shaped across the full circle, but rather two S-shapes.

Comment: yes you're correct. sorry.

Comment: Also I presume that the slopes of the "essentially linear" portions are adjustable, not fixed at 1 as you said there?

Comment: yep! you're corrrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a graph of

$$ f(x)=(\sqrt[3]{90})^2\sqrt[3]{x-90}+90\approx20.083\sqrt[3]{x-90}+90 $$
[image: Graph of S shaped curve]

Comment: works perfectly! thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.